# loading div on submit button to prevent double submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Background : my code uses master page which has frames inside and all the other navigation happens using frame and master page is used for menu purpose.
On submit button click (on all screen) , want to disable page for any further user interference. For that master page has a div and on individual page following code is written

```
var loading = window.parent.document.getElementById('dvLoading');
$(loading).show();
```

Problem: i have one frame which has couple ajax tab, on clicking on individual tab , i would like to call same div to prevent user interference while tab navigation. for which following code is written

```
$(".ajax__tab_inner").click(function() {
     var loading = window.parent.document.getElementById('dvLoading');
     $(loading).show();
});
```

This works fine untill user clicks on currently active tab, which does not remove the loading div and it remains loaded/hanging state.

kindly suggest how to prevent div loading for active tab or any other way.

Answer (score 0):

you should check if the clicked tab is the current one, and if so, cancel the rest of code.

this is an example code for this manner:

```
 $(".ajax__tab_inner").click(function() {
             // assuming that the active tab has a class called `active`
             if((this).hasClass('.active')) 
                 {
                     return false;
                 }
            var loading = window.parent.document.getElementById('dvLoading');
            $(loading).show();
        });
```

Comment: Hi ElSayed, Thanks for your suggestion, Can you pls extend it to understand, how can i assign class to current tab? are you suggesting that on tab change i keep on assigning active class by some identification of active tab?

Comment: Correct, I mean that there has to be something that Identify the active tab from the siblings.
so I thought it maybe a class or something.
cause this approach will make things easier for you to work with these tabs, and on the other hand help in fixing your current problem.
if you had a look on jQuery Ui Tabs implementation (http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) you will notice that they assign a  special class for the active tab (`ui-tabs-selected`). this is exacty what I was talking about.

Comment: if you still have problems implementing this approach, update the question with your HTML code, and maybe I can help you more. :)